# How to get nested keys in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database structure]

So I have a question is it possible to retrieve the whole child of `-Ltlu0PZaSDgydS1akRt` under object Student with the condition of (if `courseId` contains `-LuPHOGBwBLTIHn-k4zl`) the `courseId` itself is a nested object within `-Ltlu0PZaSDgydS1akRt` object.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the nested keys under courseId try the following:

```
Query databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Student").child("Ltlu0PZaSDgydS1akRt").orderByChild("-Lua7cZD1anNgKuvprjj");
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
       for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           String key = ds.getKey();
           String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
         } 
    }
} 
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Here you add a reference at node `courseId` then attach a listener and iterate inside the ids. Then using `getKey()` you can retrieve the key.

Comment: is it possible for firebase to retrieve like a child based on certain conditions such as if it contains some id that i needed then return it

Comment: Yes u can use `orderByChild("Id").equalTo(id)` but you need to have a child called "Id"

Comment: I really appreciate your help Peter!! But I think i didn't express my question clearly.. This is my bad. can u refer to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059566/how-to-return-child-of-firebase-according-to-certain-conditions

Comment: U cannot ask the same question twice, edit this question and be specific and clear with what you want